# ASP.NET Core - How to reuse methods created in one controller in another controller?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, asp.net-core

One way is to create use class inheritance, but is there any other way  I could reuse methods that I created in one controller in another controller?

EDIT: should I use a custom basecontroller like this?

---

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _identityService = identityService;
    } 

    public BaseController()
    {
    }

     //reusable methods
     public async Task<Account> GetAccount()
     {
        //code to do something, i.e query database
     }


}
```

---

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _identityService = identityService;
    } 

    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
    {

      var account = await GetAccount(); 

      //do something

      Return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do this.

Comment: This may be helpful. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264392/is-a-good-practice-to-call-a-controller-function-from-another-controller. If you still insist then cleaner approach imo is to use "RedirectToAction".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several aspects we want to touch:

- if code you have is useful in all controllers, most of the time it is good practice to create BaseApiController that will inherit from ApiController and put things that are used across all controllers there. (You also inherit your controllers from that class of course)
- if code is some kind of business logic and is not strictly speaking related to handling http request one way or another ( i.e. you have model Square and you want to calculate area and return it from controller method). Things like that you want to refactor to specific *service* which might or might not be model, dedicated service, static class or something completely different

Comment: Some methods need to query the database, so from what you are saying I should be using a custom base controller, see my example is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you find something you want to use in two places it's a candidate to be spun into it's own class.  Then both controllers can use the common class.